# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I cannot start debugging on iOS simulator for some reason. I have tried several solutions it helped in their ways I guess but the problem is not gone and I am desperate now. I don't know how exactly is this site works or is there any existing solution, but thing is I couldn't find and I need your help.

Error is here:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            9.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[9036]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee17d160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x110d142c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9036]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ee17d1b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x110d14318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/c2/_5qtd3yx59gdmf0t6qtwzskh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.pF1OXi/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirCJgdwG/temporary_xcresult_bundle
4
Invalid depfile: /Users/arnaudp/Desktop/tester/my_app/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0a3c503f4b90e814926533c60d069d61/kernel_snapshot.d
: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
HomePage.dart:3
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
```

i try here but it's work for me:

```
rm ios/Podfile

flutter pub upgrade

flutter pub get

cd ios && pod update

flutter clean && flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `HomePage.dart` remove `import 'dart:html'`. You can't have access to it in your ios build.